# How to use console.log when trying to see an output?

Tags: javascript, react-native

For example , declared `activeTabIndex`

How to see if i am setting the activeTabIndex event?

Here is the code:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setActiveTabIndex(0)} style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 4, padding: 5, alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Home height={30} width={22} fill={activeTabIndex == 0 ? "blue" : "#d4e6f1"} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Where to write console.log(activeTabIndex) or something)

Comment: `{activeTabIndex}` between the opening and closing JSX tags...

Comment: on developer tools, console.log(activeTabIndex) didnt work

Comment: you don't have to use `console.log` just use `{activeTabIndex}` in the HTML and the value will get printed in the HTML.

Comment: In `setActiveTabIndex` function have `console.log(whateverVarIsPassed)`

Comment: I just couldnt understand.. I mean i want to write to the console itself. `setActiveTabIndex()` this only sets the State, it wouldnt make sense if i wrote `setTabIndex(console.log(activeTabIndex)` because i set in there, if i wrote this, it wouldnt be set

Comment: That does not make any sense. - you could do console.log(setTabIndex (activeTabIndex)) and return the tabIndex if you wanted, but not the other way around

Comment: Okay Sir, thank you

Comment: @mplungjan could u please look at my question if u have free time? Thank you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165896/why-doesnt-tab-bar-icon-color-change?noredirect=1#comment120475827_68165896

Answer (score -1):

1. You can bind activeTabIndex to your JSX template eg. `{activeTabIndex}`
2. You could add a console.log(index) in your `setActiveTabIndex()` method to see if it is getting fired.

Comment: This is basically a consolidation of comments to the question. The question is not worth answering and should be deleted

Comment: I just couldnt understand.. I mean i want to write to the console itself. `setActiveTabIndex()` this only sets the State, it wouldnt make sense if i wrote `setTabIndex(console.log(activeTabIndex)` because i set in there, if i wrote this, it wouldnt be set